# How could I know that the (X) close button of browser is clicked?

Tags: browser, authentication, login-control

I want to track the close button of browser so that when an user clicked on that, the session can be terminated. I don't want user to be login from many places.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Single Page App? If so, just send an AJAX request in the `window.onbeforeunload` event. Otherwise, you're SOL.

You should be able to manage concurrent logins (for the same username) on your web server. Spring Security has this feature, if using Java. If not, just deny access if `user@example.com` is trying to login while `user@example.com` is already logged in.

Comment: Nope, it is a complete spring based web application. I am already using the SPRING security for concurrent login. But for a single case, when the client voluntarly close the browser at that time I want to invalidate the session.

Comment: @AmanJain ok, well that's not how browsers work. Remind your users to log out, or make your session timeout shorter